# "There is no active transaction" in Doctrine migrations

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I try to apply migrations, first three of them to create table, the last one - insert data.
When i run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` it gives me an error "There is no active transaction" after each migration and had stoped migration. So i had to run `migrations:migrate` 4 times.
Whats could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PHP 8.0, implements "isTransactional" in migration class and return false (See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/393)

Answer (score 3):

This issue existed before, but now is visible after PHP 8 PDO.

> I will quote a great explanation located at your
> `vendor/doctrine/migrations/docs/en/explanation/implicit-commits.rst`:
>
> ## Implicit commits
>
> Since PHP8, if you are using some platforms with some drivers such as
> MySQL with PDO, you may get an error that you did not get before when
> using this library: `There is no active transaction`. It comes from
> the fact that some platforms like MySQL or Oracle do not support DDL
> statements (`CREATE TABLE`, `ALTER TABLE`, etc.) in transactions.
>
> The issue existed before PHP 8 but is now made visible by e.g. PDO,
> which now produces the above error message when this library attempts
> to commit a transaction that has already been commited before.
>
> Consider the following migration.

```php
    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
        $users = [
            ['name' => 'mike', 'id' => 1],
            ['name' => 'jwage', 'id' => 2],
            ['name' => 'ocramius', 'id' => 3],
        ];

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $this->addSql('UPDATE user SET happy = true WHERE name = :name AND id = :id', $user);
        }

        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE example_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
    }
```

> When you run that migration, what actually happens with some platforms
> is you get the updates inside an implicitly commited transaction, then
> the `CREATE TABLE` happens outside that transaction, and then there
> is an attempt to commit an non-existent transaction.
>
> In that sort of situation, if you still wish to get the DML statements
> inside a transaction, we recommend you split the migration in 2
> migrations, as follows.

```php
    final class Version20210401193057 extends AbstractMigration
    {
        public function up(Schema $schema): void
        {
            $users = [
                ['name' => 'mike', 'id' => 1],
                ['name' => 'jwage', 'id' => 2],
                ['name' => 'ocramius', 'id' => 3],
            ];

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $this->addSql('UPDATE user SET happy = true WHERE name = :name AND id = :id', $user);
            }
        }
    }

    final class Version20210401193058 extends AbstractMigration
    {
        public function up(Schema $schema): void
        {
            $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE example_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))');
        }

        public function isTransactional(): bool
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> Please refer to the manual of your database platform to know if you
> need to do this or not.
>
> At the moment, this library checks if there is an active transaction
> before commiting it, which means you should not encouter the error
> described above. It will not be the case in the next major version
> though, and you should prepare for that.
>
> To help you deal with this issue, the library features a configuration
> key called `transactional`. Setting it to `false` will cause new
> migrations to be generated with the override method above, making new
> migrations non-transactional by default.

### Solution 1

Disable the parameter `transactional` in your migrations config file as explained [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.2/reference/configuration.html).

### Solution 2

Disable transactional migration only this time by adding `--all-or-nothing=0` in your `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` command.

Answer (score 0):

For me following code worked

```
public function isTransactional(): bool
{
    return false;
}
```